# django async task using django q task and redis server

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, redis

i try to follow this [tutorial](http://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for django q async tasks 
and i have install redis from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncFhlv-gBXQ) on windows 10
 (i have also rabbitqm server)

I don't get some error but my function don't execute i don't get anything from my function i think the problem  is on redis server config.

any idea ?
here the code :

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [..]+'django_q',

# redis defaults
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'redis': {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0,
        'password': None,
        'socket_timeout': None,
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'errors': 'strict',
        'unix_socket_path': None
    }
}
```

tasks.py

```
import math
import sys


def add(n1,n2):
     test=n1/n2
     return test
```

views.py

```
def app_details(request,slug):
        if request.method == "POST":
            test = request.POST.get('iy')
        t1=test
        t2=test*1542
            async('tasks.saga',t1,t2)
        return render(request, 'page.html',....
```

that message I get without error in pycharm :

```
23:54:27 [Q] INFO Enqueued 3
```

redis cmd :

[image]

redis command server :

[image]